# Terraform and container declaration for GCP - how much does indentation matter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, containers, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have defined a VM in GCP, running a `Memcached` container. Now I am in the middle of importing all of the infrastructure into Terraform. There is one little problem that I am afraid of simply ignoring and that is the indentation of the generated YAML while running `terraform plan`.

To give a little context - the Memcached VM was launched using the **GCP Launcher**. I created a bare minimum resource in TF, imported it and now I'm backtracking and trying to add all missing data into the resource definition to fully comply with the actual deployment. One thing I can't get *exactly right* is the **metadata**, namely the container spec (`gce-container-declaration`).

I have followed the example [on GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm) and created a module, where I defined everything to my best knowledge. However, when I run `terraform plan`, I get a tiny difference in indentation:

```
  ~ metadata             = {
      ~ "gce-container-declaration" = <<~EOT
          + ---
            spec:
              containers:
          -     - name: service-memcached
          -       image: launcher.gcr.io/google/memcached1
          -       stdin: false
          -       tty: false
          +   - image: launcher.gcr.io/google/memcached1
          +     name: service-memcached
          +     stdin: false
          +     tty: false
              restartPolicy: Always
          - 
          - # This container declaration format is not public API and may change without notice. Please
          - # use gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Console to run Containers on Google Compute Engine.
          +   volumes: []
        EOT
        "google-logging-enabled"    = "true"
    }
```

Is the indentation difference negligible, or am I missing something in the definition?

Module definition:

```
module "gce-container" {
  source = "github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm"

  container = {
    name = "service-memcached"
    image = "launcher.gcr.io/google/memcached1"
    stdin = false
    tty = false
  }

  restart_policy = "Always"
}
```

Comment: Is your project is new or do you have existing TF deployment on it? If so, what is it?

Comment: No TF deployment. The project has multiple deployments that have all been done through the UI or `gcloud` commands.

Comment: Is the apply work as expected ?

Comment: I haven’t done anything yet. I don’t want to blindly hit it and bring it down. That’s why I’m asking on SO.

Comment: For me, it's look good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [consulting with the module creators](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm/issues/52#issuecomment-559840658) and performing tests, it is safe to say that the **YAML** structure *is flexible* and therefore nothing breaks when such transition is performed.